# Does serving food on a hot plate really keep it warm longer?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I live in Ireland where serving food on hot plates is considered “good cooking practice” to ensure the food remains warm – I come from France where I have rarely seen it done.

I am wondering if this practice really is useful.  I assume it depends on the difference of temperature between the food and the plate, as heat won’t transfer as fast to the plate.  But wouldn’t the extra time the food remains above an “acceptable” temperature threshold just be marginal?

Comment: I think there are too many unknowns to make a theoretical prediction useful. I would resort to experiment. The hot plate will obviously have some effect, but as you say it may not be a big effect.

Comment: There is the psychological effect of having a hotter plate also, even if the food is almost the same temperature.

Comment: It also depends on the heat capacity of the plate and food. A thick heavy plate may help keep a small amount of food warm. For a flimsy little plate holding a ton of food, the initial plate temperature makes little difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if Newton's law of cooling applies . Use this [calculator](http://www.endmemo.com/physics/coollaw.php) to prove it to yourself. Assume the specific heat capacity of the plate and the food are approximately the same. Assume the heat transfer between the food and plate is much faster than to the air, and represent the initial temperature of the dish-food compound as the mass-weighted average of the food and dish temperatures. Over time, temperatures everywhere should converge anyway.

Do an experiment to test your theory.

Comment: Extract from the lab diary: "Trial 1, Apparatus: Roast chicken dinner (plate at 21.3deg), dining table, knife and fork..."

Answer (score 1):

There are two points to remember:

- The options are not "hot plate or no plate", they are "hot plate or cold plate". Bringing food into contact with a room temperature plate will cool it rapidly.
- Many plate designs have only a small area in contact with the table, and a much larger area in contact with the food.

Answer (score 0):

The plates *may* affect the food to a certain degree, but look at the whole thing.

- There's cold air *surrounding* the food.
- The plate isn't *maintained* at a high temperature (assuming).

Food kept for a long time wouldn't be kept hot for very long, unless the plate is hot enough to burn, which I doubt. I *have* seen hot plates being served, but keeping the food hot isn't the reason. It's mostly because the plates are heated to sanitize them, and served immediately after that - thus the plates remain warm.

Or, as @Kevin says, there's a psychological effect. Could you elaborate on that? :)

Comment: Disagree on both of your premises. 1. Air is a great insulator of heat, try putting the food in cold water and watch how much faster it cools down. 2. Plates are generally ceramic, which is generally dense and have good heat capacity.

Comment: Air is a good insulator, but there'd be convection too, which would keep sending cold air down towards the food. What I meant that a hot plate would keep the food hotter for a *bit* longer - until it cools down as well - the plate's cooling down too, by heat taken from the table, and radiation and again - cold air to an extent. Once the plate is cool, what difference will it make? I'm talking relatively, not absolutely.

Comment: See mark's answer. The point is to consider the cooling effects of the room temperature plate rather than the heating effects of the warm plate in heating the food.